# useEffect does not render properly with if statement

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, use-effect

In my useEffect statement if I put my sort inside of a conditional statement is does not work until useEffect is rendered again.  When I move my sort outside of the if statement it renders the first time.  Why is this and how do I fix this?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (sortBy.value === "PRICE_LOW") {
      console.log("in Here");
    }
      flights.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
   }, [flights, sortBy]);
}
```

Comment: You need to re-set `flights` after array mutation. `setFlights([...flights])`. React does not detect object's properties changes. Only object changes itself.

Comment: Can you make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?